# Why is app.use() not serving up the 'public' directory when I save even though the path is appears to be correct?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm following a slightly outdated tutorial on node and express, and my code is identical to the tutorial, but app.use is not serving up the public directory as I wish. When I go to the root localhost:3000 I still see **Weather** like in the  tags on line 19. When I delete it, I don't see anything, including the public directory's index.html file.

[image]

Here is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>From a static file.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js script:

```js
/* nodejs script that will create, configure, and start the server.

run script: node src/app.js
keep server running: nodemon src/app.js
*/

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public'); // abs path to serve


// STACKOVERFLOW -  WHY ISN'T THIS SERVING UP PUBLIC DIRECTORY?
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath)); // serve 'public' directory

// create root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Weather</h1>');
});

// create a help route
app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
    res.send([
        {name: 'Barack H. Obama'},
        {name: 'George W. Bush'},
        {name: 'William J. Clinton'}
    ]);
});

// create an about route
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>About</h1>');
});

// create a weather route
app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        forecast: 'rain',
        location: 'Los Angeles'
    });
});

// port 3000 is common development port, starts server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 3000');   // never displays in browser
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'd mark this as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `public` instead `..public`  like this 
`const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public')`

As `app.js` and `public` share the same parent directory at the same level. So `..public` will point out to dir `public` outside `src` which is not available.